# parsing string to JSON

Tags: java, json

My console prints value of String result as

```
[{"series":[ {\"data\" : [ 100.0 , 222.0 , 555.0 , 367.0 , 100.0]}],"yAxis":{\"plotLines\":[{\"dashStyle\":\"solid\",\"color\":\"black\",\"width\":\" 2.0\",\"value\":\" 27.0\",\"label\":{\"text\":\"Average\"}}],\"title\":{\"text\":\"FTFR\"}},"title":{\"text\":\"First Time Fix Rate\"},"legend":{\"backgroundColor\":\"#FFFFFF\"},"chart":{\"type\":\"line\"},"xAxis":{\"title\":{\"text\":\"Time(Years)\"},\"categories\":\[2009 , 2010 , 2011 , 2012 , 2013]}}]"
```

I need to parse the String result as valid JSON

but the following code throws exception:

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  Object obj = parser.parse(result);
```

Exception:

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: Unexpected character (\) at
>   position 14.

How can i parse this kind of string to proper  JSON?

Comment: How did you generate that string in the first place? It looks like the value of the "series" property is already JSON but has been escaped once too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
Object obj = parser.parse(result.replace("\\", ""));
```

to remove all your  `\` but it looks like a terrible hack. (By the way replacing the sequence  `\"` by `"` shouldn't be enough because there is also a `\[` that should make a problem.)

How do you get that string in your console?
It seems that the escape characters are not even systematically present.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use backslashes before double quotes. This is not correct JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have `\"`. Are you pasting this result into an IDE and you then try to parse it? (Netbeans adds `\` to any quotation marks which are within another set of quotation marks.

If on the other hand, this is exactly the type of string you are getting, you would need to do something like so:

```
        String str = "[{\"series\":[ {\\\"data\\\" : [ 100.0 , 222.0 , 555.0 , 367.0 , 100.0]}],\"yAxis\":{\\\"plotLines\\\":[{\\\"dashStyle\\\":\\\"solid\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"width\\\":\\\" 2.0\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\" 27.0\\\",\\\"label\\\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Average\\\"}}],\\\"title\\\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"FTFR\\\"}},\"title\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"First Time Fix Rate\\\"},\"legend\":{\\\"backgroundColor\\\":\\\"#FFFFFF\\\"},\"chart\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"line\\\"},\"xAxis\":{\\\"title\\\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Time(Years)\\\"},\\\"categories\\\":\\[2009 , 2010 , 2011 , 2012 , 2013]}}]\"";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"").replaceAll("\\\\\\[","["));
```

Yields:

```
[{"series":[ {"data" : [ 100.0 , 222.0 , 555.0 , 367.0 , 100.0]}],"yAxis":{"plotLines":[{"dashStyle":"solid","color":"black","width":" 2.0","value":" 27.0","label":{"text":"Average"}}],"title":{"text":"FTFR"}},"title":{"text":"First Time Fix Rate"},"legend":{"backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF"},"chart":{"type":"line"},"xAxis":{"title":{"text":"Time(Years)"},"categories":[2009 , 2010 , 2011 , 2012 , 2013]}}]"
```

In your case you might want to do away with two of the slashes in each case, I had to make them so that I can execute it on my IDE.

Comment: It shouldn't work because there remains a  `\`` before a `[`in the end of your string

Comment: @C.Champagne: Agreed. Shoudl be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with npinti You might be trying to use the backslash as the escape character but it should not be visible when you print it. So probably you might have escaped the escape character. It is bit funny when you say it like that..:)